# reason the output with null in view

Tags: java, null

```
class Test {
    public void method(Object o) {

        System.out.println("Object");
    }


    public void method(Test s) {

        System.out.println("Test");
    }


    public static void main(String as[]) {

        Test ob = new Test();

        ob.method(null);
    }

}
```

Q. Why is the output "test" ? How `null` is getting passed over here and why?